# Unique response variable for a linear model in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a loop to create linear models using the same predictor set for different responses

```
for(i in resp){
  y=data[,i]
  df=data.frame(y, modelpredictors) #this creates a temporary data frame for you 
  name=paste("MODEL", nameIndex, sep=".") #Create unique model names
  model=lm(y~.,data=df)

  assign(name, model)
  nameIndex=nameIndex+1

}
```

Later on in my code, I use a function (the dredge(), which I am looping) that needs to call the response vector, in this case "y", for each model.

I need each model to have a unique response "name" so I can call the correct vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating different models for different 'y' variables, you should just edit your fourth line to be:

```
name=paste('model',i,sep='.')
```

Then later you can loop through and call each model by using 'get()' like:

```
for( i in resp){

    model_name<-paste('model',i,sep=',')
    model<-get(model_name)

}
```